# Importing excel data to django database in parent child format

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

My requirement is to save the excel data in the django DB using import which I could do using below code. But next I want to save the data in a one to many relationship. ie. I want a unique key to be generated and saved in Main_page model and corresponding to that my uploaded excel file data should share the same primary key in the Upload model.
For eg. If the main_page has id 1, so for my complete excel data uploaded i want the data to share the same key. What changes or any link should i learn or go through. I am stuck since last few days but no luck. Thanks in advance

models.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):

    sheet_key = models.ForeignKey(Main_page)
    Student_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Total_Marks = models.IntegerField()
    Marks_Scored = models.IntegerField()

class Main_page(models.Model):
    sheet_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField()
```

views.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()


def import_data(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # Check if the form is valid
        if form.is_valid():


            request.FILES['file'].save_to_database(             # Save the file data to the database
                name_columns_by_row=1,
                model=Upload,
                mapdict=['Student_Name', 'Total_Marks', 'Marks_Scored', 'Status', 'Date', 'College_Name', 'Phone Number'])     # Columns to be mapped

            return HttpResponse("OK")

        else:       # If the form has errors show the error.
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_form.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
<body>
    <h1>{{header}}</h1>

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same by converting it to csv and then writing below function.
(I am sharing the main logic. If you need the complete logic let me know)
views.py

```
                    with open('df.csv') as csvfile:         # Reading the CSV to the model DB
                        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                        for row in reader:
                            p = Upload(Student_Name=row['Student Name'], Total_Marks=row['Total Marks'], Marks_Scored=row['Marks Scored'],
                                       Status=row['Status'], PhoneNumber=row['Phone Number'], unique_id=row['unikey'], First_Round_Interviewer_Name=row['1st  Round Interviewer Name'], Second_Round_Interviewer_Name=row['2nd Round Interviewer Name'],
                                       Third_Round_Interviewer_Name=row['Third Round Interviewer Name '], Management_Round_Interviewer_Name=row['Management/HR Round Interviewer Name'], HR_Round_Interviewer_Name=row['HR Round '])
                            p.save()        # Saving each record of the file using instance of the Uplaod model
```